# Ordered factor removes all values

Tags: r, function, variable-assignment, r-factor

(I am working in R 3.02 OSX.)

I have a data set where the variable of interest is imported as an `int` with values of 1, 2, 3 and they represent educational level.

Before conversion it was

```
 str(df$var)
 int [1:5000] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 ...
```

I tried to create an ordered factor:

```
var_name <- ordered(df$var, levels = c(1,2,3), 
                    labels = c("Undergraduate Degree", "Graduate Degree", 
                               "Professional Degree"))
```

The variable is changed to a ordered factor with three levels (I see that in the `str` function). However all the values are now gone and replaced with all `NA`s.

I am able to get what I want by simply changing `ordered()` to `factor()`:

```
var_name <- factor(df$var, levels = c(1,2,3), 
                   labels = c("Undergraduate Degree", "Graduate Degree", 
                              "Professional Degree"))
```

However, I am curious why does `ordered()` remove all the values? What did I do wrong in that function?

Comment: Can you show us `str(df$var)`? Why is one data frame `df` and another `DF`?

Comment: df and DF are just typo. Both are the same dataframe$variable.

Comment: str(UniversalBank$Education)
 Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Undergrad"<"Graduate"<..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

Comment: On a simplified example like `df <- data.frame(var=as.integer(c(1:3,2:3,1,NA)))`, your code for `var_name` works perfectly.

Comment: @mylesg please show us the variable before you convert to a factor. Your code expects a variable to have values 1, 2, and 3 in the original data frame. Please just edit your question to include `str(df$var)` before conversion to factor.

Comment: Here it is before conversion.   str(UniversalBank$Education)
 int [1:5000] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 ...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1412059).